# sys.stdout.write() - screen output vs. > redirect ('charmap' codec)

Tags: python, windows, redirect, stdout

Windows 7 & Python 3.5.2

Printing a string that contains Unicode using sys.stdout.write()

If I do 'python my.py infile' I get:

```
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 45739-45740: character maps to <undefined>
```

If I do 'python my.py infile > outfile', redirecting stdout to a file, it works fine.

I was getting that same error both ways until I did:

```
outStr = outStr.encode("utf-8").decode()
```

I'm also getting some extra '\r' chars that I have to filter out.

What is the correct way to do this consistently?

Comment: In 3.5, if `sys.stdout` is a console it uses the current output codepage of the console. All other files default to the system ANSI codepage.

Comment: `outStr.encode("utf-8").decode()` shouldn't change `outStr` at all since the default encoding for `decode` is UTF-8 in Python 3.

Comment: The troublesome strings are coming from an external source,